# VBA print webpage to PDF from Excel workbook?

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, printing

I have an Excel workbook with the below code. It is designed to navigate to google.co.uk and print the webpage as a PDF.

This is working almost fine. The code navigates to the wepbage and prints to PDF and opens the pdf document.

However, I seem to be having problem setting where I want the file to save.

I want my PDF file to always save in this location:

```
G:\QUALITY ASSURANCE\06_SUPPLIER INFORMATION
```

But for some reason it's always saving to the desktop. There is supposed to be a save as dialog box that opens but it never shows.

I have copied this code from a website to try and get me started so I don't pretend to understand all of it. I'm pretty new to VBA.

Essentially my aim is to have the webpage print to PDF automatically and save in the correct folder without the user being prompted with the save dialog box or having to hit save.

I also don't really want the PDF to open after it saves.

Here's my code. How can I get my code to do what I need?

Code

```
option Explicit
Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" _
    (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

Public Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
    (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

Public Declare Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" _
    (ByVal hWnd1 As Long, ByVal hWnd2 As Long, ByVal lpsz1 As String, ByVal lpsz2 As String) As Long

Public Declare Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" _
    (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long

Public Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" _
    (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long

Public Declare Function SendMessageByString Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" _
    (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As String) As Long

Public Declare Function PostMessage Lib "user32" Alias "PostMessageA" _
    (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long

Public Declare Sub keybd_event Lib "user32" _
    (ByVal bVk As Byte, ByVal bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)


'Constants used in API functions.
Public Const SW_MAXIMIZE = 3
Public Const WM_SETTEXT = &HC
Public Const VK_DELETE = &H2E
Public Const KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = &H2
Public Const BM_CLICK = &HF5&
Public Const WM_CLOSE As Long = &H10

Sub WebSMacro()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'set default printer to AdobePDF
Dim WSHNetwork As Object
Dim dteStartTime As Date
Set WSHNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
WSHNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter "Adobe PDF"

'get pdfSave as Path from cell range
Dim sFolder As String
sFolder = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") 'assumes folder save as path is in cell A1 of mySheets

Dim IE As Object
Dim Webloc As String
Dim FullWeb As String

FullWeb = "https://www.google.com"

'Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium


    'IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate FullWeb

    dteStartTime = Now
   Do While IE.READYSTATE <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
      If DateDiff("s", dteStartTime, Now) > 240 Then Exit Sub
   Loop

    IE.ExecWB 6, 2 'OLECMDID_PRINT, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Call PDFPrint2(Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row).Value & "_BRC_" & Replace(Range("K" & ActiveCell.Row).Value, "/", ".") & "_" & ".pdf")

    IE.Quit



Set IE = Nothing

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Sub PDFPrint2(strPDFPath As String)

    'Prints a web page as PDF file using Adobe Professional.
    'API functions are used to specify the necessary windows while
    'a WMI function is used to check printer's status.

    'By Christos Samaras
    'http://www.myengineeringworld.net

    Dim Ret                 As Long
    Dim ChildRet            As Long
    Dim ChildRet2           As Long
    Dim ChildRet3           As Long
    Dim comboRet            As Long
    Dim editRet             As Long
    Dim ChildSaveButton     As Long
    Dim PDFRet              As Long
    Dim PDFName             As String
    Dim StartTime           As Date
    Dim AcroApp


'open Acrobat and minimize
Set AcroApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")

    strPDFPath = "G:\QUALITY ASSURANCE\06_SUPPLIER INFORMATION\"

    'Find the main print window.
    StartTime = Now()
    Do Until Now() > StartTime + TimeValue("00:00:00")
        Ret = 0
        DoEvents
        Ret = FindWindow(vbNullString, "Save PDF File As")
        If Ret <> 0 Then Exit Do
    Loop

    If Ret <> 0 Then
        SetForegroundWindow (Ret)
        'Find the first child window.
        StartTime = Now()
        Do Until Now() > StartTime + TimeValue("00:00:00")
            ChildRet = 0
            DoEvents
            ChildRet = FindWindowEx(Ret, ByVal 0&, "DUIViewWndClassName", vbNullString)
            If ChildRet <> 0 Then Exit Do
        Loop

        If ChildRet <> 0 Then
            'Find the second child window.
            StartTime = Now()
            Do Until Now() > StartTime + TimeValue("00:00:00")
                ChildRet2 = 0
                DoEvents
                ChildRet2 = FindWindowEx(ChildRet, ByVal 0&, "DirectUIHWND", vbNullString)
                If ChildRet2 <> 0 Then Exit Do
            Loop

            If ChildRet2 <> 0 Then
                'Find the third child window.
                StartTime = Now()
                Do Until Now() > StartTime + TimeValue("00:00:00")
                    ChildRet3 = 0
                    DoEvents
                    ChildRet3 = FindWindowEx(ChildRet2, ByVal 0&, "FloatNotifySink", vbNullString)
                    If ChildRet3 <> 0 Then Exit Do
                Loop

                If ChildRet3 <> 0 Then
                    'Find the combobox that will be edited.
                    StartTime = Now()
                    Do Until Now() > StartTime + TimeValue("00:00:00")
                        comboRet = 0
                        DoEvents
                        comboRet = FindWindowEx(ChildRet3, ByVal 0&, "ComboBox", vbNullString)
                        If comboRet <> 0 Then Exit Do
                    Loop

                    If comboRet <> 0 Then
                        'Finally, find the "edit property" of the combobox.
                        StartTime = Now()
                        Do Until Now() > StartTime + TimeValue("00:00:00")
                            editRet = 0
                            DoEvents
                            editRet = FindWindowEx(comboRet, ByVal 0&, "Edit", vbNullString)
                            If editRet <> 0 Then Exit Do
                        Loop

                        'Add the PDF path to the file name combobox of the print window.
                        If editRet <> 0 Then
                            SendMessage editRet, WM_SETTEXT, 0&, ByVal " " & strPDFPath
                            keybd_event VK_DELETE, 0, 0, 0 'press delete
                            keybd_event VK_DELETE, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0 ' release delete

                            'Get the PDF file name from the full path.
                            On Error Resume Next
                            PDFName = "test"
                            On Error GoTo 0

                            'Save/print the web page by pressing the save button of the print window.
                            Sleep 0
                            ChildSaveButton = FindWindowEx(Ret, ByVal 0&, "Button", "&Save")
                            SendMessage ChildSaveButton, BM_CLICK, 0, 0


                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
   End If
End Sub

Function CheckPrinterStatus(strPrinterName As String) As String

    'Provided the printer name the functions returns a string
    'with the printer status.

    'By Christos Samaras
    'http://www.myengineeringworld.net

    Dim strComputer As String
    Dim objWMIService As Object
    Dim colInstalledPrinters As Variant
    Dim objPrinter As Object

    'Set the WMI object and the check the install printers.
    On Error Resume Next
    strComputer = "."
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
    Set colInstalledPrinters = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Printer")

    'If an error occurs in the previous step, the function will return error.
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        CheckPrinterStatus = "Error"
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    'The function loops through all installed printers and for the selected printer,
    'checks it status.
    For Each objPrinter In colInstalledPrinters
        If objPrinter.name = strPrinterName Then
            Select Case objPrinter.PrinterStatus
                Case 1: CheckPrinterStatus = "Other"
                Case 2: CheckPrinterStatus = "Unknown"
                Case 3: CheckPrinterStatus = "Idle"
                Case 4: CheckPrinterStatus = "Printing"
                Case 5: CheckPrinterStatus = "Warmup"
                Case 6: CheckPrinterStatus = "Stopped printing"
                Case 7: CheckPrinterStatus = "Offline"
                Case Else: CheckPrinterStatus = "Error"
            End Select
        End If
    Next objPrinter

    'If there is a blank status the function returns error.
    If CheckPrinterStatus = "" Then CheckPrinterStatus = "Error"

End Function
```

Comment: One way would be to show a filepicker and let them choose a folder location and then simply move the file from your desktop to the specified folder... assuming you know the name of the file. Delete the file if they cancel.

Comment: @GibralterTop thanks for the prompt response. I'm not sure i know how to do this?

Comment: do you know the name of the file after it is saved to the desktop?

Comment: _"Please can someone help me edit my code to get it to do what i need"_ - that's not how things work around here. I suggest you remove that, and if necessary restructure the question. Stack Overflow is not a clearing house for free labour. People are willing to help you, but they will not finish it for you - that is your job.

Comment: @GibralterTop yes i do know the name of the file once saved

Comment: @halfer thanks for the advice. Maybe you read this wrong? I was simply requesting that someone provide me help so that i could then edit the code 'help me edit', whether this help came in the form of  someone pointing me in the right direction or providing url links etc. I do not expect anyone to do my work for me. However, question has been updated. Thanks

Comment: so, you just need to move the file to where you want it to default save to? do you want them to name the file or anything or just get it to the destination?